# Remove 'None' from tracker select boxes?

Tags: tuleap

Running Tuleap 8.11.99.40 on Centos 6.7

I have created some trackers that contain select boxes and notice that they all have a possible value of 'None' when I create new artifacts.

For some of these boxes 'None' would not be a valid answer but I can't seem to remove it from the list using the usual tracker field usage tool.

Is it possible to remove 'None' from select box lists or should I be using a different field type to get what I need?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to flag you field as "Required" (in Fields Usage). None will still be displayed but users won't be able to create/update the artifact if they let "None" as a value.